# SQLite query with LAST and DISTINCT

Tags: sqlite, distinct

I have an example table:

```
ID  |  ArticleID  |  Price  |  SupplierID  |  dateAdded
1      1             100          1             2014-08-01
2      1             110          2             2014-08-01
3      2             105          1             2014-08-01
4      2             106          1             2014-08-01
5      2             101          2             2014-08-01
6      3             100          1             2014-08-01
7      1             107          2             2014-09-01
8      3             343          2             2014-09-01
9      3             232          2             2014-09-01
10     1             45           1             2014-09-01
```

I want to use .query on this table and select LAST value entered for each DISTINCT ArticleID for each SupplierID, resulting in:

```
ID  |  ArticleID  |  Price  |  SupplierID
10     1             45          1
9      3             232         2
6      3             100         1
7      1             107         2
4      2             106         1
5      2             101         2
```

I want to get price for last ArticleID entered for each SupplierID.

What should I enter into

```
public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

I came up with this so far:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_ID, DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_CENA, DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_IZDELEK_ID};
Cursor crs = database.query(true,"prices", columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);
```

but now I'm stuck:S

Any hint how to do this?

You can also suggest raw query if possible..

Comment: So, you want to generate the set of ArticleID/SupplierID pairs, and then pick the row with the maximum dateAdded for each of those pairs?

Comment: yes, something like that yes..

Answer (score 2):

Raw query would be like this:

```
SELECT ID, ArticleID, Price, SupplierID FROM your_table WHERE ID IN (SELECT max(ID) from your_table GROUP BY ArticleID, SupplierID);
```

I assumed the IDs are autoincremented and the more recent entries have higher ids. If that's not the case change the HAVING clause to operate on DATE column.

Comment: Yes, using IDs is not the solution, since some of the entries with higher dates can be filled into the DB before those entries with lower dates.

Answer (score 0):

After fidling around a bit and help of a friend I have came with SQL query that does what I want, not sure about optimization:

```
select tab.* from cene tab inner join (
    select izdelek_id, trgovina_id, Max(enter_date) as maxDate
    from cene group by izdelek_id, trgovina_id) art
on (art.izdelek_id = tab.izdelek_id) and (art.trgovina_id = tab.trgovina_id) and (art.maxDate = tab.enter_date)
```

`izdelek_id` = ArticleID
`trgovina_id` = SupplierID
`cene` is the name of a table.

Hope it helps to somebody..